# Excel 2013 crashes on exit with my Add-in

Tags: excel-2013

I have here a *.xla [PKSolver](http://www.boomer.org/software/pksolver.zip)(from Excel 2003) and saved as *.xlam for Excel 2013.
But when I load the add-in I get an error that excel crashed when I exit excel.
Moreover TH PKSOlve button is not available anymore in the Add-ins when I restart Excel. I have OS 64bit WIN 7 Prof and installed Office 2013 32bit.
Can anyone here help me in getting the xlam installed in Excel 2013?
Thanks a lot.
Walter

Answer (score 0):

I could find the reason for the disappearing of the Add-IN Tab.
See :
Solved this now but really weird solution if you enabled the Add-in whilst the Analysis ToolPaks were enabled it'd have the issue you above, but if you enabled the Add-in whilst the Analysis ToolPaks weren't ticked then went back in to it and re-ticked the Analysis ToolPaks it'd be fine and wouldn't disappear!
Was an extremely strange issue!

Source: [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/457676-excel-2013-add-ins-tab-keeps-disappearing-from-ribbon)